# how to get parent component background color in child component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to pass value of backgroundColor of Parent component Card to child component CardSubTitle and change text color based on parent backgroundColor.
React-native and babel is new for me and never used state. I tried using {...props} but it didnt worked.

Card.js

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableItem onPress={() => {}} useOpacity>
      <View style={[styles(props).card]}>{props.children}</View>
    </TouchableItem>
  );
};

Card.propTypes = {
  onPress: T.func,
  title: T.string,
  color: T.string,
};

export default Card;
```

CardText.js

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableItem onPress={() => {}} useOpacity>
      <View style={[styles(props).card]}>{props.children}</View>
    </TouchableItem>
  );
};

Card.propTypes = {
  onPress: T.func,
  title: T.string,
  color: T.string,
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: I can help you, can you use React hooks ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `props` to `children`

**But You could either**

Define Card-Background-Color in your app-theme-file like

myAppThemeFile.js

`export const APP_CARD_COLOR = 'red';`

and then reference this const in your parent or child component

**OR**

Create a component for Subtitle so you can pass props to

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableItem onPress={() => {}} useOpacity>
      <View style={[styles(props).card]}>
        <MySubtitleComponent color={props.color} value={subtitle} />  
      </View>
    </TouchableItem>
  );
};
```

**OR**
If your card's `children` are kinda not known,
I'd suggest to add **card-color** to `global` object and reference it as you wish anywhere in your app

```
const Card = (props) => {
  /**
   * Reference your card-color anywhere in your app using global.cardColor
   */
  global.cardColor = props.color; 

  return (
    <TouchableItem onPress={() => {}} useOpacity>
      <View style={[styles(props).card]}>{props.children}</View>
    </TouchableItem>
  );
};
```

**Hint**: this solution I personally don't like ... It'd be better to use a redux-action to set card-color, and pull that card-color in the component that needs it

Using `global` object is fast and easy solution ... unlike redux-solution that might take more coding ... but it's more robust and secure.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.
My card will accept dynamic color from user and its not compulsory to have subtitle inside card. Can you please suggest some more alternatives?

Comment: EI-Sahil Thank you. I will use global object as of now, and give some time in learning redux.